# Android: Center an image

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a linear layout and an image...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I dynamically center my image so that it will appear in the center of the screen on all devices?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In `LinearLayout`, use: `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

In `RelativeLayout`, use: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Comment: this only centers it at the "top" I want it centered in the middle on both x and y axis.

Comment: @Skizit: I recommend using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: +1 for RelativeLayout, use: android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: `RelativeLayout` helps

Comment: In `RelativeLayout`, there are the options `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertical` too.

Comment: Or what is in Constraint Layout ?

Answer (score 66):

If you are using a `LinearLayout` , use the `gravity` attribute :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are using a `RelativeLayout` , you can use `android:layout_centerInParent` as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm very surprised that no one voted up this answer as it was the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Technically both answers above are correct, but since you are setting your ImageView to `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content`, the image within is not centered, but the ImageView itself is.

Give your ImageView the attributes:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:gravity="center"
```

The scaleType is really only necessary in this case if the image exceeds the size of the ImageView. You may also want different scaleTypes. In conclusion, `android:gravity` is what you're looking for in this case, but if your ImageView is set to `wrap_content`, you should set the ImageView's gravity (`android:layout_gravity`) to be centered within the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this to your ImageView.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: this only centers it at the "top" I want it centered in the middle on both x and y axis.

Comment: If you want to put it in the exact middle, you can't use a LinearLayout. That's for arranging things in a list. Instead, use a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways you can center an image (or images) both vertically and horizontally in LinearLayout.

(1) Use the android:layout_gravity="center" attribute in ImageView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How this works:
the android:layout_gravity="center" attribute in ImageView centers **itself** (i.e. the image) **vertically** and **horizontally** relative to its parent (LinearLayout).

-- OR --

(2) Alternatively, you can use the android:gravity="center" attribute in LinearLayout and omit the android:layout_gravity="center" attribute in ImageView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"> 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How this works: the android:gravity="center" attribute in LinearLayout centers **its child/children** (in this case, it's the image) **vertically** and **horizontally**.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to use 'match_parent' and don't use 'fill_parent' in the LinearLayout declaration, you could check the "official
documentation" here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT
Another observation is that you need to use the ImageView as a child, then use ImageView should be self-closing; this 
means that it should end with '/>'.
Then let me show you some fast ideas:
1- As natural way

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
><ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:src="@drawable/ocean" android:scaleType="center"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Then looks like 
[image]
2- You could improvise fastly

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
/><ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:scaleType="center"/><ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:src="@drawable/ocean"
android:scaleType="center"/>
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:scaleType="center"/></LinearLayout>
```

And then looks like

[image]

3- Other ideas could be born in that way, for instance this one

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
><ImageView 
android:layout_width="300dp" 
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
/><ImageView 
android:layout_width="300dp" 
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:src="@drawable/ocean" 
/> 
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="300dp" 
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
/> </LinearLayout>
```

Lokking like this

[image]

Other possibility

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
><ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/ocean"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:scaleType="center"/><ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:scaleType="center"/>
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:background="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/ocean"
android:scaleType="center"/></LinearLayout>
```

[image]

As we have been seeing, you could use 'hidden spaces' or 'spaces with background color' to fastly solve some trouble, obviously, this is not always a possibility

Answer (score 1):

Another method.  (in Relative tested, but I think in Linear would be also works)

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:gravity="center"
```

If you use Eclipse you can choose graphical layout when *.xml file is active. On the top, you will find the Structure and option Adjust View Bounds. It will cut short all dimensions of pseudo-frame (blue rectangle) to size of your drawable file.

See also the scaleType option with make funny your image. Try it in Eclipse ;)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Logo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What did it for me was

```
LinearLayout
     RelativeLayout
          <ImageView
              width... 
              height..
     --->     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this,

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

The image will be placed at the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

**android:scaleType ="centerInside"**  --> this line use to center an image,, but you need to keep height and width of an image as wrap_context

```
 <ImageView
            android:id ="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType ="centerInside"
            android:layout_marginTop ="20dp"
            app:srcCompat ="@drawable/myimage" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but Please make your answers more descriptive to make it more understandable. Only showing the codes are not helpful for many. Try to give some inline comments or explain how your solution works and why :)

Answer (score -1):

> change layout weight according you will get....

Enter this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.03">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```