# Android ImageView layout gravity not working

Tags: android, layout, imageview, gravity

hi guys i don't have the answer for this question. Hope you could help. layout_gravity property as center it is not working when i set the scale type property to matrix. And also i am using the pinch zoom for that imageview. so if i can set the image and set if the image is small then it  would be very fine. Hoping for the better responses. Thanks in Advance...

Edit #1:
My ImageView follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear_titile_bar" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_black_logo_bg">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"   android:id="@+id/myphotos_gridview_back"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/back_gray_bt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_margin="5dip">   </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nameTitlebar" android:layout_below="@+id/linear_titile_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/title_gray_bg">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MY PHOTOS" style="@style/ivideodate.blue.large"></TextView>
</LinearLayout><!-- android:layout_above="@+id/FooterLayout" -->

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/nameTitlebar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/FooterLayout" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ProfileImageView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_photo_edit_but_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/FooterLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:background="@drawable/set_profile_pic_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:id="@+id/setprofileimage" />
    <Button android:background="@drawable/delete_photo_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/deleteimage" />

</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post code how are you set the gravity for imageview?

Comment: If you don't mind can you post whole xml file.

Comment: @user370305 hi i have updated my question with full xml...

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101874/android-center-an-image/33039444#33039444). It helped my centralize Imageview.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your linearLayout is horizontal , and the child has fill_parent as it's width. so unless, you specify the width as wrap_content and align it to center horizontal, it won't work.

Comment: i can't use wrap_content as i m using the pinch zoom.. There will not be problem if the image size is big but problem occures if the image size is small...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the android xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
       <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use gravity instead of Layout Gravity

Comment: Imageview has no field gravity, only layout_gravity

Comment: Imageview has no field gravity, only layout_gravity